# Sexual arousal to speed up recovery?

Tags: recovery, muscle-gain, muscle-recovery, testosterone, hormones

Is it a viable post-workout method to make one's self sexually aroused for prolonged periods of time?

Studies show that sexual arousal increases test. in both males and females and etc. I assume this has to stay above baseline if the subject constantly forces themselves to remain sexually aroused for a longer duration. I could do an intense workout, and supplement with porn (or even imagination alone!) for 3-4 hours straight and not include masturbation so that the urge cannot be lessened.

In such, this is forcing one's self to become as horny as possible to increase hormones. I believe this has to be a viable method since more test will speed up recovery. So would it be a smart move to make myself become sexually aroused for multiple hours, straight and steadily (no pun)?

Of course this isn't replacing sleep and a good diet, but how much can this help recovery?

I highly doubt that many people try this solely for muscle recovery aid -- maybe "edging" though.

Any feedback on my discovery? No, this is not just "abstaining" because it's not about avoiding sex/masturbation, but solely about making yourself as aroused as physically/mentally possible for prolonged periods of time. This question is not "too similar" to any questions already asked here.

Comment: I would assume that if your theory is accurate, there would need to be some way to recoup the energy "spent" over 3-4 hours of your experiment.  Seems like that would tax any reserves that would normally be used for recovery.  In my opinion, this seems like wasted effort.

Answer (score 1):

So my friends and I theorized this while in undergrad and being industrious college students we did some research and could never find any evidence that sexual arousal significantly helped or hurt training. [Here](https://lifehacker.com/how-sex-and-masturbation-affects-your-workouts-1788422698) is an article on the topic that cites additional sources.

Comment: As industrious college students, does that mean you did actual library-style research, or, given the topic, should the word "research" be in quotes?

Comment: I can't see sources cited on that article. Just a YouTube video.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very surprised if arousal had any statistically significant effect on muscle growth/recovery. By that token, testosterone levels are supposedly highest in the morning and gradually decline during the day, which would suggest working out early in the day would produce a measurable benefit. I've never seen any evidence of this.

My subjective view is this: muscle repair/growth is a 24-hour process, not something that happens for 2 - 3 hours after you work out. Therefore it doesn't matter what time of day you train, or what your arousal level is (assuming it naturally peaks and troughs during the day) as the net effect is the same.

The most important - scientifically proven - aids to recovery/muscle growth are sufficient protein intake and rest. Everything else is marginal at best, including so-called recovery supplements (many of which are gimmicks because they just provide nutrients you probably already have anyway).

Comment: Yeah and testosterone goes up and down continously during the day... you might experience a dramatic drop and then after a few minutes a peak on testosterone levels.

Comment: "My subjective view is this: muscle repair/growth is a 24-hour process, not something that happens for 2 - 3 hours after you work out." - That's true, but what OP is argueing is that you could increase the proces of muscle repair. So instead of needing 24hr, you could end up only needing 22hr? Or 20hr, or 18hr. I'm not agreeing with that OP is saying, I'm just saying that what you're saying about when you work out isn't necessarily a legit argument.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that getting yourself horny is going to raise your test by any meaningful amount.
Abstaining from ejaculating is known to raise testosterone though. Your testosterone will peak after about one week of not ejaculating and then start dropping again according to a popular study. The increase is quite minimal, is it really worth torturing yourself for a small increase in testosterone?
First make sure your routine, diet and sleep are on point because these are going to have a lot more influence and then you can worry about minmaxing your muscle gains by not touching your penis.